# Insert not working on SQLite iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, sql-insert

I am not able to understand the problem.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Build the path to the database file
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"contacts.sqlite"]];
}   

- (IBAction) saveData{
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"enter %@",name.text);

        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO EMP (name) VALUES (\"%@\")", name.text];

        //NSLog(@"enter123 %@",dbpath);

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        NSLog(@"enter789 ");

        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"Done success");

            /*status.text = @"Contact added";
            name.text = @"";
            address.text = @"";
            phone.text = @"";*/
        } 
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"fail");
            //status.text = @"Failed to add contact";
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither will anyone else if your question remains as it is. Revise the question, add more detail about any errors or warnings you're seeing. Describe what you expect to happen and what is actually happening and show what you have already tried in order to solve the problem. Without any of this, your question will be closed very quickly.

Comment: Whats the exact problem you are getting? any crash? or fail?

Comment: **ALWAYS** check return codes from EVERY SQLite operation.  And, if an operation fails, **ALWAYS** call `sqlite3_errmsg` and print the resulting message.

Answer (score -1):

use this it's help you

```
 sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK){
    const char *insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO EMP (name) VALUES (?)";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
       sqlite3_bind_text( statement,1, [name.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    }
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        NSLog(@"You have Sucessfully saved!");
    else
        NSLog(@"Failed to Save!");

       sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
```

Comment: Would benefit greatly from proper indentation.

Comment: And why do you execute the step even if the prepare failed?